# How to scroll to the bottom of a TWebBrowser document in Delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of my displayed `TWebBrowser` document programmatically.

I've tried using the `scroll` method:

```
uses
  MSHTML;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  Document := WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Document.parentWindow.scroll(0, Document.body.offsetHeight);
end;
```

I also tried using `ScrollIntoView(false);`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  Document := WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Document.Body.ScrollIntoView(false);
end;
```

Comment: `scroll` method is provided for backward compatibility only. The recommended way to scroll a window is to use the `IHTMLWindow2::scrollTo` method (which does work). That method also doesn't require the use of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `JavaScript` code to scroll it:

```
const
  jsScrollDown = 'window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);';
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  Hwn: IHTMLWindow2;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  if not Assigned(Doc) then Exit;
  Hwn := Doc.parentWindow;
  Hwn.execScript(jsScrollDown, 'JavaScript');
```

Or next generation, `TEdgeBrowser` supports directly scripts execution:

```
EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript(jsScrollDown);
```

Running JS code, allows scrolling easily to any element of the HTML document.

Using MS interfaces, without JS, it could be done like:

```
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  Hwn: IHTMLWindow2;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  if not Assigned(Doc) then Exit;
  Hwn := Doc.parentWindow;
  Hwn.scrollTo(0, (Doc.body as IHTMLElement2).scrollHeight);
```

Be aware, MS interfaces works in [legacy](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2022/06/15/internet-explorer-11-has-retired-and-is-officially-out-of-support-what-you-need-to-know/) IE mode only, not supported by Edge engine.